# HTACCESS Rewrite Rule Results in a Redirect Loop

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite, apache2, reverse-proxy

I've set up Apache behind NGINX proxy and my HTTPS redirect (rewrite) rule results in a redirect loop. It looks like `HTTPS` is returned as false despite I'm setting the environmental variable properly.

My rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

My environmental varaiables:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=on
```

And when I do a `var_dump` in PHP, I can see that the variables are set properly:

```php
[HTTPS] => on
```

I'm wondering why `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]` always returns true even if the URL is accessed over HTTPS and the environmental variable is set?

p.s. As a fix, if I use `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]` in place of `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]`, the redirect loop goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `%{HTTPS}` variable is handled by mod_ssl but in your case since https is handled by nginx, not Apache, `%{HTTPS}` is `off`.

Also this variable is not an environment variable so your `SetEnvIf` can't be recognized, you should have to write `%{ENV:HTTPS}`. But, it worth noting that `SetEnvIf` are interpreted after mod_rewrite so it won't work neither.

The right way, in your case, as you find out, is to use `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https [NC]`.